# Build Window Server 2012 R2 to host MS SQL Server 2015 capacity 200GB

Tags: sql-server, host, windows-server-2012-r2

I am not a network or server person and building window server 2012 R2 or whatever version to host MS SQL Server 2015/2016 is new to me. I don't even know where to start or how to begin but would like to learn and get into it.

Could someone point me in the right direction or provide some guildline on how I can approach this ? Also I was curious what does the R2 in window Server 2012 R2 mean or stand for ?

I saw window Server 2012 R2 and they go from as low as 45 bucks to as much as I guess couple of hundreds or thousands of dollars. Why is all these price range ?

Can I just buy a desktop computer and with my IP address do this from scratch, or what do I need ?

My goal is to host sql Server 2015/2016 on a Server so it can be access by many people or application or remote access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it say 2012 R2? Usually that means a release number. But SQL Server 2015/16 will install just fine on Windows 2012. Please make sure that your machine (if its going to be used in production environment) is backed up on a very regular basis and has some form of RAID 5 or RAID 10.

SQL Server pricing is dependent on several factors including the edition of SQL Server (Enterprise,Standard) and the number of cores (CPUs) in the host machine. For an exact price you want to contact Microsoft but here is a list to get you started:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016-pricing

Here is a list of things you should do as you install SQL Server:
https://www.sqlshack.com/best-practices-after-installing-microsoft-sql-server/

If you want to restore the database to a specific point in time you should learn how to do log backups but at a minimum learn to set up a backup job. Many users do an incremental backup every night and a full backup every weekend but your needs will determine the backup schedule.

SQL Server is a very powerful and useful product. You should work through a book on SQL Server administration - Micrsoft SQL Server 2012 Management and Administration by Mistry is one of many wonderful books you can use.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the great information. What machine, is it a desktop machine or a server machine to host the window and sql server. What about data center and the capacity set up for the sql server being at say 500 GB. I don't know how I can set it up.  I think I need the enterprise edition since, other people, application and remote connection need to access it ?

Comment: I think backing up is very important and thanks for pointing that out.  Do you back up by the PC or physical server or by window server or by SQL server ?

Comment: You need to backup the server machine at the windows level. You also need to backup up SQL Server (the objects in SQL Server) either using SQL Server backup (which is free with SQL Server) or a third party backup tool. If you anticipate a 500GB database you almost certainly need to host it on a server machine that has access to a SAN or a series of RAID hard disks. Please mark the answer as correct if you feel it is.

Comment: How many user do you say is the number that would need a physical server vs a PC ?  Let's say only 100 user are going to use it. I meant they aren't going to program it but just to use the file or apps that connects to the sql server. I don't know if that is considered as using it or not.  I also think maybe 250 GB instead. And where is the RAID hard desk in the PC or physical server or window Server or sql server ?

Comment: A server is a robust machine that may have multiple power supplies, faster memory, dual nic cards among other things. You are still very vague on how SQL Server will be used. 250GB is a lot of data and almost always there are programs that manipulate the data. You need to do a lot of research and planning or you should get help for this. Once the system is set up and users start creating and manipulating data it becomes difficult to change bad design. Its unlikely that 250 word Qurora answers will suffice for your needs.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, I'm trying it out but have never set up an sql server before. I only purchase the cheap one that I use on my local machine.  Which version sql server should I buy, I think the 5 user cal but does that mean only 5 people can have access to the program that  use the data from it or 5 SQL programmer ?

Comment: actually for the immediate foreseeable future the SQL server that I am using it for will be to store data. At this point I don't think it will run into the millions. It will be use to store updated data and to keep a history of old datas.  And it will be use to create views, store procedures and links to excel and use python programs and forms to access and manipulate it. It will be also use to access by ms sql server report services. From this what do you advise and which SQL version should I get, the enterprise or the standard one and the difference of the two ?

Comment: at least for the foreseeable future and time being, I will have complete control of the window and SQL server, data and programs so I think it's manageable.

Comment: If you are doing development you can get a developer version of SQL Server for around $50 which is exactly equivalent to Enterprise. Standard is a lot cheaper then Enterprise but Enterprise has all kinds of very useful features so you have to determine if you need Enterprise. I would start with either developer and then when its ready for production use Standard until the business requirements forces you to use Enterprise features. But read about and learn SQL Server before you put it into production.

Comment: But I need a sql server that put into window server 2012 R2 that can be access by different utilities. Do you think I still need just the developer edition ?  Developer maybe good for me on my local machine to build with but not on the server.

Comment: The difference between Standard and Enterprise is real money ($6874 per core for enterprise vs $1793 per core for standard plus  CAL fees). I don't know what features you need and how many CAL LIcenses you will need. The developer is for you to model your needs and see what features you will really use and need. Please get help from Microsoft for up to date pricing.

Comment: I need management studio, reporting services, and maybe the analysis and integration too. I never tested the analysis or integration so I don't know much of it. I think user cal is better than device cal but I don't understand what is 5 vs 1 user cal mean.  Can a 1 user cal Developer edition allow me to install it on window service and create programs that allow anyone to access it as long as I gave them the program or files to access it ?

Comment: Management Studio is free and, reporting services, and  analysis and integration services all come with Standard. There are other features that come with Enterprise that don't come with Standard. Please contact a Microsoft Rep or you can post to the Database Administrative Quora forum for advice about CAL's. Working for Fortune 100 companie's I don't do licensing agreements.